# Create a .wav file from the microphone's data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want just record audio from the microphone and save it in a .wav file.
This is my c# code:

```
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage);

            // Add wave header:

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            bw.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });

            bw.Write((int)fileStream.Length + 36);

            bw.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });

            bw.Write((int)16);

            bw.Write((short)1);
            short channels = 2;
            bw.Write(channels);
            int samplerate = 8000;
            bw.Write(samplerate);
            short BitsPerSample = 8;
            bw.Write((int)(samplerate * ((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8)));

            bw.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8));

            bw.Write(BitsPerSample);

            bw.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
            int DataLength = (int)fileStream.Length;
            bw.Write(DataLength);


            fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 44, (int)stream.Position);

            fileStream.Position = 0;

            bw.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
```

if I open the .wav file with VLC, it doesn't reproduce anything.
If instead I open the file in this way ( see below ), just after I saved it, then it reproduce the sound correctly:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(duration)];
 using (IsolatedStorageFile userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream openfilestream = userStore.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                openfilestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

  SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(buffer, microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
  soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
  soundIsPlaying = true;
  soundInstance.Play();
```

### Edited code

I just edit the code above as Adriano said (but it doesn't work):

```
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage);
            fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 44, (int)stream.Position);


            // Aggiunta wav header:

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            bw.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });

            bw.Write((int)fileStream.Length - 8);

            bw.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });

            bw.Write((int)16);

            bw.Write((short)1);
            short channels = 1;
            bw.Write(channels);
            int samplerate = 8000;
            bw.Write(samplerate);
            short BitsPerSample = 8;
            bw.Write((int)(samplerate * ((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8)));

            bw.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * channels) / 8));

            bw.Write(BitsPerSample);

            bw.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
            int DataLength = (int)fileStream.Length - 44;
            bw.Write(DataLength);

            fileStream.Position = 0;

            bw.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: looks like you are using microphone.SampleRate to read the file, but hard coding it when writing, are you sure they match?  Same for channels, you write channels 2 hard coded, but read in mono.  Are you sure they match?

Comment: I am not sure and I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

These lines look suspicious:

```
bw.Write((int)fileStream.Length + 36);
// ...
int DataLength = (int)fileStream.Length;
// ...
short channels = 2;
// ...
int samplerate = 8000;
```

Channels should probably be 1 if it's mono.

Seems like fileStream.length would always be 0, you just created it above, and it seems like what you intended to write there is the length of the actual wav data.  stream.length?

samplerate of 8K is pretty low quality, but that might just be what you are getting I guess.  It would be better to use the actual microphone properties to determine this.

Also, it might be easier to read if you set 0x52494646 and 0x57415645 to a couple of constants instead of using your char arrays.

```
The canonical WAVE format starts with the RIFF header:

0         4   ChunkID          Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
                               (0x52494646 big-endian form).
4         4   ChunkSize        36 + SubChunk2Size, or more precisely:
                               4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size)
                               This is the size of the rest of the chunk 
                               following this number.  This is the size of the 
                               entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes for the
                               two fields not included in this count:
                               ChunkID and ChunkSize.
8         4   Format           Contains the letters "WAVE"
                               (0x57415645 big-endian form).

The "WAVE" format consists of two subchunks: "fmt " and "data":
The "fmt " subchunk describes the sound data's format:

12        4   Subchunk1ID      Contains the letters "fmt "
                               (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
16        4   Subchunk1Size    16 for PCM.  This is the size of the
                               rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
20        2   AudioFormat      PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
22        2   NumChannels      Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
24        4   SampleRate       8000, 44100, etc.
28        4   ByteRate         == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
32        2   BlockAlign       == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               The number of bytes for one sample including
                               all channels. I wonder what happens when
                               this number isn't an integer?
34        2   BitsPerSample    8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
          2   ExtraParamSize   if PCM, then doesn't exist
          X   ExtraParams      space for extra parameters

The "data" subchunk contains the size of the data and the actual sound:

36        4   Subchunk2ID      Contains the letters "data"
                               (0x64617461 big-endian form).
40        4   Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               This is the number of bytes in the data.
                               You can also think of this as the size
                               of the read of the subchunk following this 
                               number.
44        *   Data             The actual sound data.
```

via:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: ok I have just edited the code as you said ( see above please ). But it doesn't work :(

Comment: it does not look to me like you have edited the code in the way that I described, look at all occurrences of `fileStream.Length`

Comment: yes but now "fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 44, (int)stream.Position);" stay before that occurrences.